# webpack modernizr default.a.prefixed is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack, modernizr

I am trying as follows to webpack an existing code that uses Modernizr:

`package.json`

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        ...
        "modernizr": "^3.5.0",
        "modernizr-loader": "^1.0.1",
        "webpack": "^3.6.0"
      }
    ...
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.min-[hash:6].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{ test: /\.modernizrrc.js$/, use: ['modernizr-loader'] },
                { test: /\.modernizrrc(\.json)?$/,
                  use: ['modernizr-loader', 'json-loader'] },
                {test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|ico|mp3|ogg|mp4|webm)$/,
                 loader: 'file-loader',
                 options: {name: 'media/[name].[ext]'}},
                { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
                { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader',
                  options: {minimize: true, attrs: 'img:src link:href source:src'} }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
      alias: {
        modernizr$: path.resolve(__dirname, "./config/.modernizrrc")
      }
    }
};
```

`index.js`

```
...
document.write(require("./js/main.js"));
```

`js/main.js`

```
import Modernizr from 'modernizr';

...

$(function () {
    ...
    var transform = Modernizr.prefixed('transform');
    ...
}());
```

`config/.modernizrrc`

```
{
  "minify": true,
  "options": [
    "setClasses"
  ],
  "feature-detects": []
}
```

This however is giving me a runtime error in browser (there are no npm run build or webpack error):

```
Uncaught TypeError:     main.js:355
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_modernizr___default.a.prefixed is not a function
    at main.js:355
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:373)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.min-cfe9d2.js?cfe9d2040bf0ebd00205:20867)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap cfe9d2040bf0ebd00205:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap cfe9d2040bf0ebd00205:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.js:10253)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap cfe9d2040bf0ebd00205:19)
    at module.exports.ctor.super_ (bootstrap cfe9d2040bf0ebd00205:62)
    at bootstrap cfe9d2040bf0ebd00205:62
```

I came this far following some Webpack tutorial and Modernizr sample code. This code works if, insteda of webpack I directly include the Modernizr from `index.html`.

I can also see that `Modernizr` object has no `prefixed` function (`console.log`):

```
Modernizr {}
__proto__:
    on:ƒ (n,e)
    _config:
        classPrefix:""
        enableClasses:true
        enableJSClass:true
        usePrefixes:true
        __proto__:Object
_q:[]
_version:"3.5.0"
__proto__:Object
```

I am quite new to webpack + Modernizer and not quite sure what I am doing wrong here.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to have fixed the problem:

package.json

```
{
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "modernizr": "^3.5.0",
    "modernizr-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.6",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0"
  }
...
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
ModernizrWebpackPlugin = require('modernizr-webpack-plugin'),
ModernizrConfig = require('./config/modernizr.config.js'),

module.exports = {
...
module: {
    rules: [{test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|ico|mp3|ogg|mp4|webm)$/,
             loader: 'file-loader',
             options: {name: 'media/[name].[ext]'}},
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader',
              options: {minimize: true, attrs: 'img:src link:href source:src'} }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    ...
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        hash: true, template: './index.html'}),
    new ModernizrWebpackPlugin(ModernizrConfig)
]
};
```

js/main.js

```
<strike>`import Modernizr from 'modernizr';`</strike>
...
$(function () {
    ...
    var transform = Modernizr.prefixed('transform');
    ...
}());
```

config/modernizr.config.js (renamed from .modernizrrc)

```
{
    "minify": true,
    "options": [..., "prefixed", ....],
    "feature-detects": [...]
}
```

index.html

```
...
<body>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modernizr-bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Notes:**

- `[hash:6]` doesn't work in `modernizr-webpack-plugin`'s config `filename`property, `[hash]` works though
- couldn't auto inject generated `modernizr-bundle.js` into `index.html` yet